# Left and Right background images, in CSS

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to use one image for a background, and two others for the left and right sides?
I know this is possible using a table of some sort, but I'd like this to be scalable.

```
header {background-image: x.jpg left(y.jpg) right(z.jpg);}
```

Does something exist like this?

With tables, I was thinking something like this is possible:

```
<td background="x.jpg">Left side</td>
<td background="y.jpg">Center, title.</td>
<td background="z.jpg">Right side</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a single background (which may be an image) to a single element.

If you want three backgrounds, you need three elements, and if you want those elements to appear side by side then you have to position them side by side (which can be done any number of ways). You can further manipulate the position of the background of an element using `background-position` which you may have to because the alignment of backgrounds is totally independant.

The onyl reason this works for a table (which you should avoid like the plague unless the content of the table is actually *tabular data*) is because you have three elements.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple background-images are coming, and there is a limited amount you can do right now with what support there is for CSS3 border-image, but at the moment there is no good, simgle-element, cross-browser way to do it.

Comment: I'm looking forward to it, but for now it looks like I will have to use tables.

Comment: If you looked at the problem and saw tables as the only answer and you worked for me, you would immediately be able to say you *used to* work for me. Use tables *only* when you are working with tabular data.

Comment: Haha, I hate tables just as much as the next guy, I was joking. Point taken, however.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
#hb-header {
height: 64px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#hb-header .headleft {
float: left;
width: 64px;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('HeaderLogoLeft.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
}
#hb-header .headcenter {
height: 100%;
}
#hb-header .headright {
float: right;
height: 100%;
background-image: url('HeaderLogoRight.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
}


<div id='hb-header' class='hb-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'>
    <div class='headleft'></div>
    <div class='headright'>
        <div style='margin-right: 72px;'>
            Version ${buildNumber}
            <div id='login' style='display:none;'><span id='login-user'></span> 
                <button type='button' id='logout' onclick="logout();" style='font-size:70%; line-height:1.0; padding:0.25em;'>Sign Out</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='headcenter'>
        <h3 style='margin-left:72px;'>Hello World</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```